# Moschip UA0025c USB - ethernet adapter don't work after upgraded to el capitan

Tags: macos, usb, drivers, ethernet, osx-el-capitan

I have upgraded my Macbook Air CTO 8Gb ram (mid 2015) to El Capitan.
After that the USB ethernet adapter don't working... first always said cable unplugged, after i removed the interface i can't add back. I also tried to reinstall the moschip usb driver and edit the /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/NetworkInterfaces.plist
but no luck.

**UPDATE**
Finally I find this in console:
`01/10/15 14:40:12,461 com.apple.kextd[45]: ERROR: invalid signature for com.moschip.driver.moschipUsbEthernet, will not load`

I googled it and run:

`sudo nvram boot-args="kext-dev-mode=1 rootless=0"`

then booted to recovery mode (hold command + R at boot)

and in terminal run `csrutil disable`

reboot and then driver loads again... huhh :)

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**, Apple's new "System Integrity Protection" (SIP) prevents any modifications to system files, as well as unverified kernel extensions.

Those drivers are using unverified extensions, and are blocked.

For the moment `csrutil disable` in recovery mode is the only solution.  But - it disables SIP system-wide.   It's probably worth asking if you'd rather spend $20 for a legit adapter and keep your system secured.

**Long answer** with step-by-step instructions: [How to use a Generic USB 2.0 10/100M Ethernet Adaptor on Mac OS 10.11 El Capitan](http://inkandfeet.com/how-to-use-a-generic-usb-20-10100m-ethernet-adaptor-rd9700-on-mac-os-1011-el-capitan)

Answer (score 0):

I did the `sudo nvram boot-args="kext-dev-mode=1 rootless=0"` followed by rebooting in recovery mode and `csrutil disable`. After I do `csrutil disable` I get a success message and it tells me to reboot.

However, when I'm back in the OS, I do `csrutil status` and I get this.

```
System Integrity Protection status: enabled (Custom Configuration).

Configuration:
    Apple Internal: disabled
    Kext Signing: disabled
    Filesystem Protections: disabled
    Debugging Restrictions: disabled
    DTrace Restrictions: disabled
    NVRAM Protections: disabled

This is an unsupported configuration, likely to break in the future and leave your machine in an unknown state.
```

My usual USB network connection still says the cable is unplugged (it isn't) and there isn't anything on the `+` menu for me to add different.

Any tips?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This is **not** an answer to the original question. If you have a new question please [ask your own question](http://superuser.com/questions/ask) (referencing this one for context if it helps).